# Represent Python-generated data with D3.js chart

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, matplotlib, nvd3.js

Here is my problem: I have written a Python script to analyse some DNA sequences of a certain bacteria and I need to plot the output. I use Matplotlib to render the charts and HTML/CSS for texts and tables.

Recently I found the following javascript library: http://d3js.org/ and the best layout for my data would be: http://www.theguardian.com/world/interactive/2013/apr/30/violence-guns-best-selling-video-games

Unfortunately I have never used javascript so I'm experimenting with the code of the web page, trying to generate a similar code with Python and my data. It takes a lot of time.

Does anyone know how I could do this more quickly? I found nvd3 on Github which is very helpful but there is no example for the chart I need.

Thanks a lot !

(I will definitely learn javascript soon but it is impossible at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely worth learning d3. In the meantime this module might be a good one to look at?

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh

You might find this bit interesting in their examples:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/burtin.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Malcolm Murdoch :)

Circos looks amazing. I'm probably going to use it for now. But the two other solutions you suggested are nice as well and with a bit of tweaking it should give something close to what I want.

Yes I'm really motivated to learn D3!

Have a nice week end